# How do I find the inverse of a derivative at $x=-1$?

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

> Let $f(x)=x^3-3x^2-1$, $x\geq2$. Find the value of $\left(df/dx\right)^{-1}$ at $x=-1$.

This is the work that I've done so far:

1. Found $f'(x)=3x^2-3x$
2. Found the inverse of $f'(x)$ ►$3y^2-6y-x=0$
3. Found the roots of $y$ ►$[6±(36+12x)^{1/2}]/6$
4. Plugged $x=-1$ into $[6±(36+12x)^{1/2}]/6]$ and got $[3±(6)^{1/2}]/3$

Is $[3±(6)^{1/2}]/3$ the correct answer?

Comment: Derivative is incorrect.

Comment: You say you found the inverse, but you didn't. At least it's now shown in your question that you did.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^3-3x^2-1$.

- $f'(x)=3x^2-6x$
- For $(f'(x))^{-1} $ complete the squares. $y=3x^2-6x+3-3=3(x-1)^2-3\implies x=1+\sqrt{\dfrac {y+3}{3}},\:y\in[-3,\infty)$

Comment: The question changed from $df^{-1}/dx$ to $(df/dx)^{-1}$. Thats why the earlier question seemed  absurd.